# R: dplyr summarize, sum only values of uniques

Tags: r, unique, dplyr, summary

I am having trouble with a pesky command I would like to have for an analysis of a summary, for which I'm using the `dplyr` package. It's easiest to explain with some example data:

```
structure(list(Date = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), 
    Name = structure(c(3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("George", 
    "Jack", "John", "Mary"), class = "factor"), Birth.Year = c(1995L, 
    1995L, 1997L, 1995L, 1999L, 1995L, 1999L, 1997L, 1997L), 
    Special_Balance = c(10L, 40L, 30L, 5L, 10L, 15L, 2L, 1L, 
    100L), Total_Balance = c(100L, 100L, 50L, 200L, 20L, 200L, 
    20L, 100L, 1600L)), .Names = c("Date", "Name", "Birth.Year", 
"Special_Balance", "Total_Balance"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Two simple summaries are my goal: first, I'd like to summarize just by `Date`, with the code seen below. The part that is wrong is the `total_balance_sum` calculation, in which I want to sum the balance of each person but only one time for each person. So for instance, the result of my command for `Date=1` is `total_balance_sum=100`, but what it should be is 150 (add `total_balance` of 100 for Jack once to `total_balance` of Mary of 50 once). This wrong calculation obviously messes up the final `pct` calc.

```
example_data %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>% 
  summarise(
    total_people=n_distinct(Name),
    total_loan_exposures=n(),

    special_sum=sum(Special_Balance,na.rm=TRUE),
    total_balance_sum=sum(Total_Balance[n_distinct(Name)]), 
    total_pct=special_sum/total_balance_sum

  ) -> example_summary
```

In the second summary (below), I group by both date and birth year, and again am calculating `total_balance_sum` incorrectly.

```
example_data %>% 
  group_by(Date,Birth.Year) %>% 
  summarise(
    total_people=n_distinct(Name),
    total_loan_exposures=n(),

    special_sum=sum(Special_Balance,na.rm=TRUE),
    total_balance_sum=sum(Total_Balance[n_distinct(Name)]), 
    total_pct=special_sum/total_balance_sum

  ) -> example_summary_birthyear
```

What is the correct way to achieve my goal? Clearly the `n_distinct` I'm using is only taking one of the values and not summing it properly across names.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you show your desired output too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little unclear on what you may be asking for, but does this do what you'd like?: (just for the first example)

```
example_data %>% 
  group_by(Date, Name) %>% 
    summarise(
      total_loan_exposures=n(),
      total_SpecialPerson=sum(Special_Balance,na.rm=TRUE),
      total_balance_sumPerson=Total_Balance[1])%>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>% 
  summarise(
    total_people=n(),
    total_loan_exposures=sum(total_loan_exposures),
    special_sum=sum(total_SpecialPerson,na.rm=TRUE),
    total_balance_sum=sum(total_balance_sumPerson)) %>% 
  mutate(total_pct=(special_sum/total_balance_sum))-> example_summary

> example_summary
Source: local data frame [3 x 6]

    Date total_people total_loan_exposures special_sum total_balance_sum  total_pct
    1    1            2                    3          80               150 0.53333333
    2    2            2                    4          32               220 0.14545455
    3    3            2                    2         101              1700 0.05941176
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately it does not. The total balance for Date 1 here is 250 (takes the sum of John twice and Mary once). However, I'd like the total balance to equal 150 - in other words, I only want to count John's total one time (even though he has 2 special balances). So the total_balance_sum for Date 1 would be 150, Date 2 would be 220 (John: 200 + Jack: 20 = 220) and Date 3 would be 1700. Thank you!

Comment: So the special balance would be summed per person, but the total balance is taken just once, per date?

Comment: Yes - total balance takes only one total for a person-date occurrence, but the special balance is summed as many times as the person appears in the person-date pair.

Comment: Yes, that works great! Thank you - I did not realize this was a pretty complicated demand. One more question - on the second task, I attempted to add Birth.Year to the second group_by command, but received the error: Error: unknown column 'Birth.Year'

Comment: well when you summarised the data in the first `group_by %>% summarise()` command, you didn't add a column for `Birth.Year`, so it doesn't exist in the new dataset. 

I would, in the first `summarise()` add a column that is `Birth.Year=mean(Birth.Year)`

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and persistent help. Learned something new today!

Answer (score 1):

For the second example (for the first, just remove the Birth.Year):

```
library(dplyr)
example_data %>% group_by(Date, Birth.Year) %>%
                 mutate(special_sum = sum(Special_Balance),
                        total_loan_exposure = n( )) %>%
                 distinct(Name, Total_Balance) %>%
                 summarise(Total_balance_sum = sum(Total_Balance),
                           special_sum = special_sum[1],
                           total_people = n(),
                           total_loan_exposure = total_loan_exposure[1],
                           special_sum/Total_balance_sum)
```

Comment: This is an elegant solution - thank you for sharing it. For my own knowledge, what are you doing with the two commands that include the [1] command?

Comment: taking the first value of each group- the special_sum and total_loan_exposure were done as mutate so we didn't drop the rest of the rows, but we only needed the value once. Summarise requires only one row, so taking the first is a way to get the value. you can check this by stopping after the intial mutate and seeing all the values are the same for each group.

Comment: Instead of taking the `mean` of two exact numbers, he instead took just the first index of that number. It's another way to get to the same thing as I did above in my solution with `mean`.  If you aren't aware of how to index vectors, data.frames, lists, I'd recommend [this](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html) chapter of hadley wickham's advanced r book.

Comment: `[1]` is much faster than `mean()`!

Comment: Yes, I know. My solution was inferior in terms of processing time. I was just indicating that, in terms of the end result, we did the same thing.